# What is the maximum radius around the player that allows for plants grow in servers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I play on a server in minecraft and the best way to make money on there is to make a 7x7 chunk cactus farm because that's the servers render distance. I just recently heard about there is a 128 block radius around the player for random ticks and I can't wrap my head around what that means in context of a real farm. does that mean there is actually an 8 chunk radius around me that will grow cactus even if the server render distance is 7?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.
The Minecraft wiki says:

> In Java Edition, chunks with a load level of 31 (see [Chunk loading](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk#Chunk_loading)) or below and with centers within 128 blocks of a player are ticked on every game tick.
>
> [Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tick#Chunk_tick)

And if I understand correctly, random ticks will still occurr in chunks, that are <render distance + 1> chunks away from you. (As stated [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk#Chunk_loading))

You can go ahead and expand that farm :D
Happy building and stay safe!